# Only accept two or four digit years from users

Tags: java

I have to accept a date from a user via a simple inputText field (JSF 2).  I created a Converter so I can validate the date and now I am running into trouble with 1, 3, and 5+ digit years.  All dates entered by the user will be either today or in the future (up to a reasonable maximum).

The below solution accepts three different date formats and will correctly handle 2 and 4 digit years (in the former case by using set2DigitYearStart to convert them to 20XX).  I am completely stumped how I can handle other wrong dates.

### Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String date = "2/3/111"; // This should be rejected!

    List<String> datePatterns = new ArrayList<String>();
    datePatterns.add("MM-dd-yy");
    datePatterns.add("MM.dd.yy");
    datePatterns.add("MM/dd/yy");

    for (String pattern : datePatterns) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        formatter.set2DigitYearStart(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse("1/1/2000"));
        formatter.setLenient(false);
        try {
            System.out.println(formatter.parse(date));
            break;
        } catch (ParseException ignore) {
            System.out.println("Date format doesn't match pattern: " + pattern);
        }
    }
}
```

### Examples That Should be Accepted

- 02/02/02
- 02/02/2002

### Examples That Should be Rejected

- 02/02/1
- 02/02/333
- 02/02/55555

### One Approach

Get some theoretical maxDate and yesterday's date, then compare the output.  This seems wrong somehow, though...

```
        SimpleDateFormat f4 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Date maxDate = f4.parse("01/01/2099");

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
        Date minDate = f4.parse(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Comment: It might not be possible with that function.  From the docs: For parsing, if the number of pattern letters is more than 2, the year is interpreted literally, regardless of the number of digits. So using the pattern "MM/dd/yyyy", "01/11/12" parses to Jan 11, 12 A.D.

Comment: I am avoiding that by using `set2DigitYearStart`. Please run the above code with 01/11/12. You will get back 01/11/2012.

Comment: Alas, 111 is not a 2-digit year.

Answer (score 1):

Add some specific validation after your parsing is finished to reject any years that are out of range ie getYear() < 1000 and getYear() > 9999

Warning this code is not compiled or tested as I am typing on a tablet.

```
    String dateStr = "2/3/111"; // This should be rejected!

    List<String> datePatterns = new ArrayList<String>();
    datePatterns.add("MM-dd-yy");
    datePatterns.add("MM.dd.yy");
    datePatterns.add("MM/dd/yy");

    Date date = null;
    for (String pattern : datePatterns) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        formatter.set2DigitYearStart(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse("1/1/2000"));
        formatter.setLenient(false);
        try {
            date = dateformatter.parse(dateStr));
            break;
        } catch (ParseException ignore) {
            continue;
        }
    }
    if (date != null) {
        Calendar cal =  new GregorianCalendar (date);
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        if (year() < 1000 || year() > 9999) {
            System.out.println("Date format doesn't match pattern: " 
                 + datePatterns);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Date format doesn't match pattern: " 
                 + datePatterns);
    {
```

Comment: That's what I am thinking about now too. Could you provide a specific code snippet, please?  All user-submitted dates will be in the future (within reason).  I will edit my answer to post the code that I have so far.

Comment: I see what you mean now, but  `getYear()` has been deprecated and I want to avoid shipping with deprecated code.